# How to return the list, [book], from database = (person, [book]) when the person is found

Tags: database, list, haskell, tuples

I need to create some functions in Haskell.
The types are:
type Person = String
type Book = String

```
type Database = [(Person, [Book])]
```

I wrote this code, but it only works when the person has one book in the [book]. It returns [] when the person has more than 1 book in [book].

#books returns a list of the books a person is borrowing

```
    books  :: Database -> Person -> [Book]
    books db person1 =  [ [book] | (person, [book]) <- db, person == person1]
```

#borrowers returns a list of people who are borrowing a book

```
borrowers :: Database -> Book -> [Person]
```

Comment: Just delete the brackets around `book` everywhere it appears.

Comment: You likely want `[ book | (person, books) <- db, person == person1, book <- books ]`. Never use `[x]` unless you mean a list of length one.